# How to print a modified Word-template from C#?

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word

I created a program reads a Word-template and modifies it with certain information. But now I would like to print the document without saving it.

```
 Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
 Document wordDoc = new Document();
```

How can I print or print-preview `wordDoc`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `document.PrintOut()` method is what you're looking for.

Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b9f0ke7y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can use print dialog

```
using (PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog())
            {
                pd.ShowDialog();

                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\documents\DOCNAME.DOC");

                info.Verb = "PrintTo";
                info.Arguments = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

                info.CreateNoWindow = true;

                info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                Process.Start(info);
            }
```